# Google won't sign in when Scope is added on Google Fit API

Tags: android, scope, google-fit

I'm trying to add scopes on my API client. However when I add any scopes, it won't let me sign in. However if I remove the scopes, I'll be able to sign in. Can anyone help me figure this out?

I'm using Fitness API.

When it's just `.addApi(Fitness.API_HISTORY)` it works. But when I try to add a scope, it won't go past the login/auth screen.

Thank you!

Edit: I tried two approaches

1) I left the authentication to fitness api using startResolutionForResult during which logcat reads the error as 
SIGN_IN_REQUIRED (To which the accounts pop up, however after selecting nothing happens).

2) When I created a custom sign in flow through different intent and set the account in this api client it gives me error SIGN_IN_FAILED.

In both the cases when i remove scopes it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicSensorsApi/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basicsensorsapi/MainActivity.java). It stated that you need to have a `GoogleApiClient` that will authenticate the user and allow the application to connect to Fitness APIs. The scopes included should match the scopes your app needs. Authentication will occasionally fail intentionally, and in those cases, there will be a known resolution, which the `OnConnectionFailedListener()` can address.

You can also see [here](http://orange.dataart.com/how-to-use-googlefit-api/) a sample code that creates a client that should ask `Fitness.API` for read permissions and add permissions for reading `(SCOPE_LOCATION_READ)` and writing `(SCOPE_BODY_READ_WRITE)`.

Comment: I Literally followed the first example you gave. I just wanted to see if I'm getting connected using the client provided in the example. It gives the same error. SIGN_IN_REQUIRED (I believe this comes just before sign in pop up ) So for my issue there's not even any ouptup